# "you should make on your homework on time" is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

I want to specify a condition which is "make homework on time. don't postpone".

Can I use "make on" to describe this situation?

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: No, you cannot. You don't use *make* this way. You'd use another verb like complete, finish, submit, depending on what your purpose was.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not grammatical.

The usual form is "You should submit your homework on time." or "You should turn in your homework on time."

Even if it were proper grammar, at least to me, 'making' homework speaks only to completing it but says nothing about actually giving it to the instructor.

Comment: Or simply '_Do_ your homework'.

Comment: Again, "Do your homework", at least to me, speaks only of completing the work not giving it to the instructor. The latter is the real point to the time limit (you of course have to complete it before handing it over but completing the work is only part of the task).

Comment: I assumed the OP to mean "Do your homework now, don't put it off."